# Using jquery .attr - change src of iframe to be "script.php?=" + (#url).text

Tags: jquery

I have a simple text box and button.

When clicked the button should change the src attribute of an iframe as follows:

```
src="**script.php?=**(value of text box)
```

I have managed to get the iframe to work when simply changing the src to be only the contents of the
text box using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Change iFrame on a Button Click Event
    $("#myButton").click(function(event){
        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', $('#url').val());
    });
});
```

How can i add the "script.php?=" before the $('#url').val()

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Change iFrame on a Button Click Event
    $("#myButton").click(function(event){
        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', 'script.php?=' + $('#url').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var prefix = 'script.php?=';
    // Change iFrame on a Button Click Event
    $("#myButton").click(function(event){
        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', prefix + $('#url').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure thing :)  As an aside, there seems to be a missing query string parameter name... e.g., script.php?<some-param>=<some-value> (this was hinted at by @Tomasz's suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Am I not thinking correctly, or you just need the:

```
$("#myIFrame").attr('src', 'script.php?param=' + $('#url').val());
```